# Rails make devise JSON API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest, devise

I was confused about how to set devise as `JSON` API.

I took a look on this [script](https://gist.github.com/jwo/1255275), but I encounter some trouble.

First, I created an **controller/api** folder and put `registrations_controller.rb`, and `sessions_controller.rb`.

Then I modify **routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users
namespace "api", :as=>:api do
  devise_for :users
end
```

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Api::RegistrationsController < Api::BaseController

  respond_to :json
  def create
    user = User.new(params[:user])
    if user.save
      render :json=> user.as_json(:auth_token=>user.authentication_token, :email=>user.email), :status=>201
      return
    else
      warden.custom_failure!
      render :json=> user.errors, :status=>422
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I tried to send `post` request to `http://localhost:3000/api/registrations/create`, it threw error

```
No route matches [POST] "/api/registrations"
```

How do I modify the `routes.rb`, so I can send the `post` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've created custom controller you need to specify router for him:

```
resources :registrations, only: [:create]
```

If you are not going to use devise controllers you can disable their routers, but don't remove them.

```
devise_for :users, skip: :all
```

Comment: I need some features of devise. Thanks, I can send request now

Comment: Now I'm too working on devise integration with client through json.

Comment: Do you follow tutorial or some useful reference?

Comment: I'm using devise only to have devise model and to send mailers (routers disabled) . For angular2 use angular2-jwt library. Follow this article http://adamalbrecht.com/2015/07/20/authentication-using-json-web-tokens-using-rails-and-react/ to use json web tokens.

Comment: I've tried to use `devise_token_auth` but it was pain.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it all.